# Bohmian vs Copenhagen Interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, wavefunction-collapse, bohmian-mechanics

Is there any experiment that could settle the debate between De Broglie - Bohm Pilot Wave Theory and the Copenhagen Interpretation?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Bohmian mechanics it's really an interpretation in a sense and so its predictions are the same as for standard QM

Comment: What about the differences between QFT and the determinism of Pilot Wave Theory? Is there any way to experimentally prove that one is correct?

Comment: Bohmian mechanisc afaik is non relativistic qm interpretation. All relativistic experiments in high energy physics can be calculated with the Copenhagen interpretation .

Comment: I do not think there is any debate about the Copenhagen interpretation being correct due to inconsistencies about what an observer is. Regarding bohmian vs other interpretations, having hidden variables always leaves open the possibility of eventually detecting them. But it would imply new physics, as both theories predict the same for standard particles.